# Derivatives and Increasing/Decreasing functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Please read this paragraph:

> Let the function f be continuous on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$, then $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ in $(a,b)$.

My question is why $f$ needs to be differentiable on the open interval not on the closed interval?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this website.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition.**  A function $f$ is said to be *increasing* on $[a, b]$ if for each $(x_1, x_2) \in [a, b]$ with $x_1 < x_2$, $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

**Theorem.** Let $f$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$. Then $f$ is increasing on $[a, b]$ if $f'(x) > 0$ for each $x \in (a, b)$.

The proof of this result is based on the Mean Value Theorem.

**Mean Value Theorem.**  Let $f$ be continuous on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$.  Then there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that 
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$$

We will assume the Mean Value Theorem to prove the theorem stated in your question.

**Proof.** Let $x_1, x_2 \in [a, b]$, with $x_1 < x_2$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, it is continuous on the closed interval $[x_1, x_2]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(x_1, x_2)$.  By the Mean Value Theorem, there exists $c \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that 
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1}$$
Multiplying both sides of the equation by $x_2 - x_1$ yields
$$f'(c)(x_2 - x_1) = f(x_2) - f(x_1)$$
Since $f'(x) > 0$ for each $x \in (a, b)$ and $c \in (x_1, x_2) \subseteq (a, b)$, $f'(c) > 0$.  Since $x_1 < x_2$, $x_2 - x_1 > 0$.  Thus, the left hand side is the product of two positive numbers, so $f(x_2) - f(x_1) > 0$, which is what we needed to show.$\blacksquare$

Therefore, it is sufficient that $f'(x) > 0$ on the open interval $(a, b)$.  It may be the case that the right-sided derivative at $a$ is positive or that the left-sided derivative at $b$ is positive, but that is not necessary for the claim to hold.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ and $b$ are endpoints, we do not know the behavior of the function as it is approaching those values from outside the interval. The rate of change at a single point is given by taking the limit definition of the derivative from both sides of the point. If they equal, the derivative exists at that point. But since we cannot take the limit from both sides, we do not know the rate of change at the endpoints. Thus we cannot tell if they are increasing or decreasing. That is why we use an open interval.